# Slave with a pouch

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a 50s-60s sci-fi movie involving a man stranded on a planet that meets a runaway slave with a pouch filled with pills that allow you to tolerate the atmosphere. The slave also had a band (maybe on their neck or wrist?) that the slave owner could activate pain. I’m not sure they are able to remove the band, but the slave owners try and track them that way. The two of them hide from spaceships searching for the runaway slave. It may have been on Venus. The slave wears a Roman type skirt and is dark haired.

Other than the slave owner complex, the movie was mostly about the 2 characters interacting and learning from each other. It was so long ago, I hope this is accurate info.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like Robinson Crusoe on Mars.  From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058530/) (emphisis mine):

> During a flight to Mars in the spaceship Mars Gravity Probe 1, Commander Christopher 'Kit' Draper and Colonel Dan McReady are forced to deviate from an asteroid and they leave their spacecraft in pods. Draper lands on the surface of the Red Planet and survives. He learns how to produce oxygen and while exploring the planet, he finds McReady dead in his crashed pod. He finds also the monkey Mona and brings the animal to the cave where he is sheltered. He learns that he can breathe the Martian air for short periods but needs also oxygen. But Mona finds water and an edible plant in the underground. .After a long period alone, Draper feels the loneliness. One day, he sees a spacecraft landing on Mars and he believes it might be the rescue team to save him. **But he finds aliens working on the planet and some of them are slaves. One of them flees and stumble with Draper and he names him Friday.** Now he needs to find a way to be rescued and return to Earth.

[image]

Comment: Great movie and is undoubtedly the correct answer.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the timely response.